# How to measure exactly what "data out" in Azure web app?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app in Azure, which has roughly 100k visitors a month, with less than 2 page views pr session (purely SEO visitors).

I just studied our Azure bills, and was shocked to find out that during last month we `3.41 TB` of data out.

Terabyte.

This makes absolutely no sense. Our average page size is less than 3mb (a lot, but not 30mb which the math would say). The total data out should in practice be:

3431000 (mb) / 150000 (sessions) = 23mb pr session, which is absolutely bogus. A result from a service such as Pingdom says:

[image: result from Pingdom]

(Seems Stack.Imgur is down - temp link: http://prntscr.com/gvzoaz )

My graph looks like this, and it's not something that just came up. I have not analyzed our bills for a while, so this could easily have been going on for a while:

[image: Azure data out]

(Seems Stack.Imgur is down - temp link: http://prntscr.com/gvzohm )

The pages we have most visits on are an autogenerated SEO page which reads from a database with +3mio records, but it's quite optimized and our databases are not that expensive. The main challenge is the data out, which costs a lot.

However, how do I go about any test this? Where do I start?

**My architecture:**

I honestly believe that all my resources are in the same area. Here is a screenshot of my main killers of usage - my app and database :

**App:**

[image]

[image]

**Database:**

[image]

**All my resources:**

[image]

Comment: Is your Web App deployed to the same region as the other services it uses (database, storage, cache, etc)?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yeah :-) And if i limit the spending down to region, it's all in one region. Unfortunately!

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Are we charged for egress if a web app is deployed in say region 'A' and our database, or other resources, are in region 'B'?

Comment: @RandyMinder Yes. Anything that leaves a region is treated as egress. So, if the OP's database were in a separate region, there could be significant egress charges (from both regions).

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Yikes! I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard - Would this help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-download-azure-invoice-daily-usage-date

Comment: @RandyMinder Not really, it just shows I use a lot of money every day :D

Comment: Anything that is not internal to an Azure region is charged. Data in, out or between Azure regions is all charged. Sounds like your architecture crosses data centers, which is a common cause. Move your Azure resources to the same data center or adjust your architecture to do once-only distribution of data so that you dont cross datacenters in processing your requests.

Comment: Data IN is not charged, only data OUT: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I wish this was the case, but it honestly doesn't look like it - I added some pics from Azure :-)

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard - what about other resource groups?

Comment: There is also a lot of SQL in there - are you querying it frequently from on-premises SSMS? Or have on premises jobs that act on SQL data? Any VPNs?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-your-bill to see if that helps you to analyze the cost, and to further pinpoint the underlying cause.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Added my resource groups, but none of them outside "North Europe" are used and is not related. I could delete them of course, but doesn't change anything.
We don't have VPN's.
The SQL - we only use it from our website and some webjobs (which is attached to the Azure Web App). They all use Entity Framework but absolutely not a lot. Our more crazy job runs 10min every night writing 5k+ records

Comment: It's like a needle in a haystack without having access to your sub. Maybe open a ticket with MS or find a technician who can hop on a shared screen and look it over. Things like connecting on-prem reporting tools to Azure SQL can also run up the bandwidth. You can can also use resource tagging in Azure to help clarify your billing, and possibly give you more traceability.http://www.azurefieldnotes.com/2016/07/18/azure-resource-tagging-best-practices/

Comment: Do you have some sort of Application Insights telemetry active that generates loads of data and driving cost?

Comment: Uh `Page Size 2.2mb` you set the caching headers so subsequent requests for a page aren't 2.2mb, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some very good help from a Ukraine developer I found on Upwork, we've finally solved the issue.

The challenge was in our robots.txt.

It turned out, that we had SO many requests on our pages - and we have 3.6 mill address pages - that it simply was a HUGE amount of requests. That's why the data out was so big.

We have now solved it by:

- Adding a robots.txt which disallow all bots but Google and Bing
- Adjusted the Google crawl speed in the Webmaster Tools
- Adjusted our sitemap from monthly to yearly changefreq for our address pages to avoid re-crawling

I'm happy!

Answer (score 0):

Follow guidance given in [Understand your bill for Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-your-bill).
Review billing from subscription level perspective.

Find out whether egress is sended/requested into/from azure services in other regions or largely requested from website visitors. Verify backup panel of web app as well or any other backup running regularly.

Review performance monitoring or performance test. Any tests from other regions responsible for larger egress?

Find out if egress follows site load during business times. If not dig deeper.
Find out if SEO visitors trigger any downloads, if yes adjust links accordingly.